# skipbib without BibLaTeX

Tags: bibtex, natbib

Is there any way to use `skipbib` or equivalent in regular BibTeX with `natbib` and without using BibLaTeX?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is no.

To use the option `skipbib` you have to use `biblatex`.